# RabbitMQ - disable Automatic Requeueing on consumer timeout

Tags: rabbitmq

I have multiple clients reading from the same Rabbit MQ Queue, the client pull the messages and perform multiple action on the message including (a non-transactional actions such as uploading to SFTP).

which means the message processing cannot be roll back automatically.

The problem is when the client crashes or turned off unexpectedly, the message is requeued, and gets pulled by another client.

Am aware of the redeliver flag that is set to true incase of requeued message, but is it possible to move these message to dead queue for example ?